# Where to find some real programming assignments for a beginner webdev?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

**Hello, folks!**

So here I am - a total beginner in webdev without any profound education on the topic, but still aiming to get a real webdev job sometime soon.

And while the assignments in the courses I've taken employ practical use of the languages(HTML, CSS, PHP, JS, jQuery), they nevertheless lack real-life examples, like something that a real client might want.

Googling on programming challenges as to the aforementioned languages gave out mostly the same; I mean yes, there were some interesting things, but they're still far from the real clients' demand, IMO.

**So the question is:** where can a beginning webdev find some real assignments to perform in order to comprehend the gist of modern webdev through practice and become able to answer the clients' possible demand? Just for the sake of experience, that is, payment is not obligatory.

Any links/replies will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Definitely not here

Comment: @C0dekid Oh, okay, didn't know that. Gonna resort to Googling, then, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Links**

For real beginner: https://www.codecademy.com/

But the best thing you can do is trying to implement an own idea / copying an existent idea ... Just think of something basic.

If you need any help, use google first and then ask on stack-overflow to solve your problem.